# Allowing X-axis labelOverlap on a column chart in HighCharts..?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to allow X axis label overlapping on a column chart in HighCharts but it doesn't seem to 'take'. In the API, it seems to say this should be done as follows:

```
  xAxis: {
        categories: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January2', 'February2', 'March2', 'April2', 'May2', 'June2', 'July2', 'August2', 'September2', 'October2', 'November2', 'December2','January3', 'February3', 'March3', 'April3', 'May3', 'June3', 'July3', 'August3', 'September3', 'October3', 'November3', 'December3'],
        labels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        
        }
    },
```

It seems simple enough but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Is this a bug or is there some other setting needed?

https://jsfiddle.net/khfyxLq1/

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all of the categories you need to also set `step` to 1.

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: [...],
    labels: {
      allowOverlap: true,
      step: 1
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gc2hetpj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step